# Making a variable change with keydown

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey, false);
function checkKey(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "37") {
   x = x--;
  }
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
```

When I do this, pressing the left arrow doesn't change x. Therefore, "test"s innerHTML doesn't change, it stays at 50. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most certainly changes the variable, you're just not updating the HTML.

Place the `innerHTML` line **inside** the event handler, so it updates when someone presses a button, and not just on pageload

```
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey, false);
function checkKey(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "37") {
   x = x--;
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
```

Note that `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is not consistent, and according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
>   browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you change it outside the function.

**JS:**

```
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey, false);

function checkKey(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "37") {
    x--;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/DaCurse0/pen/VKQYJb

Answer (score 0):

Use x - 1 instead of x-- and place innerHTML inside the if condition

```
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey, false);
function checkKey(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "37") {
    x = x - 1;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
```

Here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2oz87hvr/